# Regexp to identify given IPv4 address is Class 'C' or not in Tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

This is a code which is used to find whether IP address belongs to class C or not. But every time when i compile, it shows error. Help me to rectify it.

Code:

```
gets stdin ip

regexp {(19[2-9]|2[0-1]\d|22[0-3])\.(0\d\d|1\d\d|2[0-5][0-5])\.(0\d\d|1\d\d|2[0-5][0-5])\.(0\d\d|1\d\d|2[0-5][0-5])} $ip d

puts "$d is a class c ip address"
```

Answer (score 3):

## Doing this Properly with `scan`

A regular expression is really the wrong tool for this, as regular expressions are not really designed for parsing number ranges (unless you're writing a low-level parser). Much better to parse into pieces and then use numeric checking.

```
# Check that the string contains a dotted quad
if {
    [scan $ip "%d.%d.%d.%d" a b c d] == 4 && 
    ($a >= 192 && $a <= 223) &&
    ($b >= 0 && $b <= 255) &&
    ($c >= 0 && $c <= 255) &&
    ($d >= 0 && $d <= 255)
} then {
    puts "$ip is a class C IP address"
}
```

You are *recommended* to use `ip::normalize` from the [Tcllib **ip** package](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/dns/tcllib_ip.md) prior to parsing in order to cope with the strange things that are actually legal IP addresses.

```
package require ip

# Note the simpler expression: normalizing handles the awkward cases for us
scan [ip::normalize $ip] "%d.%d.%d.%d" a b c d
if {$a >= 192 && $a <= 223} {
    puts "$ip is a class C IP address"
}
```

If someone gives you bad input, you'll get a nice clean error describing what the problem is rather than a weirdly broken program.

---

## Using Regular Expressions

This sort of thing is why Zawinski's Aphorism exists:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

There are problems for which regular expressions are the right solution. ***THIS IS NOT ONE OF THEM!***

If you must use regular expressions, try this:

```
regexp {^(?:19[2-9]|2[0-1]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){3}$} $ip d
```

Yes, that's horrible. Here it is in expanded form, with some comments.

```
^                 # Anchored at the start of the string!
(?:               # Parse the first quad; 192..223 (NB: non-capturing group)
    19[2-9]
|
    2[0-1]\d
|
    22[0-3]
)
(?:               # And three sets of what matches the other quads
    \.            # Literal period
    (?:           # Parse a number in 0..255
        \d{1,2}
    |
        1\d\d
    |
        2[0-4]\d
    |
        25[0-5]
    )
) {3}             # Here's where we ask for this three times
$                 # Anchor at the end of the string
```

The reason this is so messy is handling those number ranges; REs are simply not a great tool for doing that.

Comment: Given that tcllib's `ip` package is recommended, an alternative is to use [`ip::isOverlap`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/dns/tcllib_ip.md#21), e.g. for class C: `ip::isOverlap 192.0.0.0/3  [ip::normalize $ip]`.